# How to bold the text of a row cells in python docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I am generating a doc using python docx module.
I want to bold the specific cell of a row in python docx

here is the code

```
book_title = '\n-:\n {}\n\n'.format(book_title)
book_desc = '-: {}\n\n:\n{}\n\n :\n{}'.format(book.author,book_description,sales_point)


row1.cells[1].text = (book_title + book_desc)
```

I just want to bold the book_title.
If I apply a  style it automatically applies to whole document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I understand it:
Paragraph is holding the run objects and styles (bold, italic) are methods of run.
So following this logic here is what might solve your question:

```
row1_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run(book_title + book_desc).bold=True
```

This is just an example for the first cell of the table. Please amend it in your code.

Answer (score 7):

A cell does not have a character style; character style can only be applied to text, and in particular to a *run* of text. This is in fact the defining characteristic of a run, being a sequence of characters that share the same character formatting, also known as *font* in `python-docx`.

To get the book title with a different font than the description, they need to appear in separate runs. Assigning to `Cell.text` (as you have) results in all the text being in a single run.

This might work for you, but assumes the cell is empty as you start:

```
paragraph = row1.cells[1].paragraphs[0]
title_run = paragraph.add_run(book_title)
description_run = paragraph.add_run(book_desc)
title_run.bold = True
```

This code can be made more compact:

```
paragraph = row1.cells[1].paragraphs[0]
paragraph.add_run(book_title).bold = True
paragraph.add_run(book_desc)
```

but perhaps the former version makes it more clear just what you're doing in each step.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the docx module, you can style your text/paragraph by explicitly defining the style.

In order to apply a style, use the following code snippet referenced from docx documentation [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html#apply-a-style).

```
>>> from docx import Document
>>> document = Document()
>>> style = document.styles['Normal']
>>> font = style.font
>>> font.bold= True
```

This will change the font style to bold for the applied paragraph.

Comment: I have to give style to row cells not to paragraph. I have done the styling for paragraph Need to row cell.

Answer (score 1):

In python-docx, the styling of any character in a docx template document can be overridden by the use of [Rich Text](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#richtext) styling. You should provide a context variable for the particular character/string that needs styling in your template, at the position of the character/string. This variable maps to the `RichText` object that has the style definition(that you define in your code), to style the character/string. To make things clearer, consider an example template doc "test.docx" that contains the following text:

> Hello {{r context_var}}!

The `{{..}}` is the jinja2 tag syntax and `{{r` is the RichText tag that overrides the character styling. The `context_var` is a variable that maps the styling to your character string.
We accomplish Rich Text styling like this:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, RichText
doc = DocxTemplate("test.docx")
rt = RichText() #create a RichText object
rt.add('World', bold=True) #pass the text as an argument and the style, bold=True
context = { 'context_var': rt } #add context variable to the context and map it to rt
doc.render(context) #render the context
doc.save("generated_doc.docx") #save as a new document
```

Let's look at the contents of "generated_doc.docx":

> Hello **World**!

I'm not sure how your template is designed, but if you just want the `book_title` as bold, your template "test.docx" should have text like:

> Title:-
>
> {{r book_title_var}}

The code should be modified to:

```
book_title = "Lord of the Rings" #or wherever you get the book title from
rt.add(book_title, bold=True)
context = { 'book_title_var': rt }
```

generated_doc.docx:

> Title:-
>
> **Lord of the Rings**